# Pronunciation of multivariable function $f(x,y,z)$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, terminology, pronunciation

Can someone tell me how is $f(x,y)$ and $f(x,y,z)$ is pronounced? Is $f(x,y)$ read as f of x and y? Is $f(x,y,z)$ said as f of x, y, and z? Thank you.

Comment: How would it matter? Different people pronounce it differently. If you are studying from a class, I suggest you use the pronunciation your teacher uses. I personally tend to use both (```f x``` and ```f of x```), depending upon the situation.

Comment: Up to you. I would read $f(x,y)$ as "$f$ of $x$ $y$", and I've also heard people say "$f$ of $x$ and $y$". For $f(x,y,z)$ I would say "$f$ of $x$ $y$ $z$", but I've also heard all sorts of variants. In general, when reading $f(x_1,\dots, x_n)$, I say "$f$ of ex one (up) to ex n"